# Fragile and verbose code using xml-conduit

Tags: xml, haskell, conduit

I built a GPX parser using [XML-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) and have had issues with overly verbose and fragile code for identifying elements and skipping unwanted tags.

**Identifying elements (a minor annoyance)**

I am explicitly ignoring name space by comparing only `nameLocalName`s.  I guess the correct way is to hardcode the right namespace(s) into the program and have a helper construct my element names for comparison in the `tag*` functions?  This is slightly annoying as I must support at least two different name spaces (GPX 1.1 and 1.0) that are sufficiently similar that they require no code changes for my uses.

**Skipping elements**

GPX is largish and the set of custom extensions is larger.  Because the tool I'm building needs limited information I decided to ignore particular tags along with all of their sub-elements.  For example:

```
<trkpnt lat="45.19843" lon="-122.428">
    <ele>4</ele>
    <time>...</time>
    <extensions>
         ...
    </extensions>
</trkpnt>
```

To ignore `extensions` and similar tags with numerous sub elements I made a sink that would consume elements till the end element `Event`:

```
skipTagAndContents :: (MonadThrow m) => Text -> Sink Event m (Maybe ())
skipTagAndContents n = tagPredicate ((== n) . nameLocalName)
                                    ignoreAttrs
                                    (const $ many (skipElements n) >> return ())

skipElements t = do
        x <- await
        case x of
                Just (EventEndElement n) | nameLocalName n == t -> Done x Nothing
                Nothing -> Done x Nothing
                _ -> return (Just ())
```

It seems there should be a `tag*` variant that will do this for me (succeed without all children being consumed) but that fact that there isn't suggests I am missing a simple combinator or should send a patch - which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the namespaces at all, it might be simplest to just strip them out entirely, using something like `Data.Conduit.List.map stripNamespace`.

Frankly, I don't really use the streaming interface that often myself; almost all of my work involves the DOM (`Text.XML`) or cursor interfaces. So it's entirely possible that there are missing combinators. But in this case, I believe you can simplify the implementation a lot, since `tagPredicate` shouldn't allow the inner `Sink` to read past the end of the element. So you can rewrite `skipTagAndContents` as:

```
tagPredicate ((== n) . nameLocalName) ignoreAttrs (const Data.Conduit.List.sinkNull)
```

You should test that before just dropping it in, I could be remembering some of the details of the streaming interface incorrectly.

Comment: I had similar code and it results in errors such as `XmlException {xmlErrorMessage = "Expected end tag for: Name {nameLocalName = \"metadata\", nameNamespace = Just \"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\", namePrefix = Nothing}", xmlBadInput = Nothing}`.  So for now I'll stick with my implementation that is explicit about the end tag.  The stripNamespace will clean up somethings though - thanks!